# Change NSUrl to QLPreviewItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How can I convert `NSUrl` to `QLPreviewItem`? In the `QLPreviewItem`.h, it is written that the below category makes `NSURL` instances as suitable items for the Preview Controller:

```
@interface NSURL (QLPreviewConvenienceAdditions) <QLPreviewItem>
```

How can I use it if in my code I have:

```
- (id <QLPreviewItem>) previewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller previewItemAtIndex: (NSInteger) index
{       
        NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[filenamesArray objectAtIndex:index] ofType:nil];
        NSURL *url =  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        return //QLpreview item from URL;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or using Swift:

```
func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
    let resumeUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "resume", withExtension: "docx")!
    return resumeUrl as QLPreviewItem
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just return the NSURL, it will work.

I've been using this:

```
if([downloadData writeToURL:self.fileUrl options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error])
(...)
```

And then I used the same URL as QLPreviewItem:

```
- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return self.fileUrl;
}
```

Comment: It works; but I get a warning: Returning 'NSURL *__strong' from a function with incompatible result type 'id<QLPreviewItem> _Nonnull'

Comment: That's odd. QLPreviewItem also defines an NSURL category to enable simply passing NSURL's as return. Alternatively, you could make your own class that implements QLPreviewItem protocol.